# Why is my R bar chart (geom_bar) not appropriately filling color based on the provided variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-bar, aesthetics

This is a bit of a newbie question.  I am using the package "nycflights13" in R, and "tidyverse".

```
library(nycflights13)  
library(tidyverse)
```

I am trying to get a bar chart that shows the total number of flights by airline/carrier, and have it color each bar by the number of flights that occurred each month.

I can get a simple bar chart to show with the following:

```
ggplot(flights) +  
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=carrier))
```

When I try to color it with the month, it doesn't change anything.

```
ggplot(flights) +  
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=carrier, fill=month))
```

The graph generated by the code above looks exactly the same.

It seems to work when I do the opposite... if I create a chart with "month" on the x-axis and color by carrier, it works just like I would expect.

```
ggplot(flights) +  
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=month,fill=carrier))
```

I assume it has something to do with discrete vs continuous variables?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this   `ggplot(flights) +    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=carrier, fill=as.factor(month)))`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!  Is there a reason why it needs the "as.factor" part?  I think I just don't understand that portion yet.

Also, if you put this as an answer I think I can mark it solved?

Comment: Great! In this case it's impossible for `ggplot2` to understand how to map the continuous month variable onto the bar chart by airline carrier. Especially since the data looks like `flights$months ([1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...)`. Converting to factor lets `ggplot2` process 'there are these many segments to fill, and they have this much volume'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this has to do with discrete vs continuous variables. `as.factor()` will convert month to discrete factors.

```
ggplot(flights) + 
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=carrier, fill=as.factor(month)))
```

For fun, there is a way to override `geom_bar`'s built in `stat_count` default. This requires adding a dummy variable to flights, to use as a `y`, and sorting the data by month (or you get weird artifacts). Look at the help document about `?geom_bar()`.

```
flights$n<-1

flights%>%
  arrange(month)%>%
  ggplot(aes(carrier, n, fill = month)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="blue", high="red")
```